# Opera doesn't play video from video element

Tags: html, opera, html5-video

I have an HTML page on my server with the following content:

```
<video controls src=mvi.ogv> </video>
```

I'm trying to open this in Opera. It loads the page, shows the controls, but not the movie, though it downloads part of the file (as showed by the server logs).

This works perfectly in Firefox and also works in Opera if I open it as a file directly from explorer.

The server I'm using is Cherokee.

Does anybody have an idea about what might be wrong with this?

**Edit**: I just realized something - on the computer that I test with I have Opera portable. And also it seems to run fine on another computer with Opera installed fully (not the portable version). So it seems to be something related to the portable Opera.

I read about the gstreamer DLLs and they seem to be in the right spot. Is there any way to check if something is missing or not installed correctly?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have quotes around "mvi.ogv", so something like:

```
<video controls src="mvi.ogv"></video>
```

Comment: I have tried both ways. The example from Opera site is without quotes and they say it should work without problems.

Comment: Don't do it without quotes, regardless. We'll need more code to solve this one.

Comment: Check my edited question - maybe I should close this question and add a new one...

Comment: MUST you absolutely have it working on opera portable? It's not exactly the most heavily developed browser on the planet...

Comment: Yes :) That's my main browser (the best there is ;)) and long story short I have to use the portable one because I don't have administrative rights on the machine I'm using for development (complicated reasons)